# Writing style when a question mark, apostrophe mark, and a comma come together

Tags: sentence-structure, punctuation, question-marks

I'm writing a sentence -

> If you have a question on 'How to make french fries?', here is the answer.

MS Word shows an error because of those three tiny creatures - a question mark, a closing inverted comma, and a comma itself.

> ?',

Now, I wonder what to omit?

Question mark is required because it **is** a question. I must close the *quote*, so apostrophe sign is *also* required. A comma is also required because the sentence *pauses* there.

How to write it correctly?

Comment: [Grammar Girl gives advice from the AP Stylebook and Chicago Manual of Style.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/combining-quotation-marks-question-marks-and-commas-whew)  AP says "leave out the comma", Chicago says "question mark, comma, close quotes".

Comment: The piece enclosed in quotes is not a question but a free relative clause--in effect it is a nominal, the object of the preposition *on*--so it should not be followed by '?'. And I wouldn't enclose it in quotes, either, or capitalize *How*.

Comment: I agree that the question in question isn't actually a good example of this, but the general issue is still a valid one.  For example, you could reasonably phrase a sentence **"If your question is 'How do I make french fries?', we have a problem."**

Answer (score 1):

I think it largely depends on style and manual guide you or your editor use. I don't think "how to make French fries" is necessarily a question that requires a question mark. The interrogative or relative adverb "how" could head a noun phrase which is the complement (object) of the preposition "on". Now, if we agree that the how phrase is not a question, we can punctuate the sentence as follows:

> If you have a question on "how to make French fries", here is the
>   answer.

or

> If you have a question on how to make French fries, here is the
>    answer.

In the first example, the quotation marks are used to emphasize the details of the question. I don't think there is a specific rule on which quotation mark to use.

Answer (score 0):

> The one thought that keeps running through my brain is, “Is anyone else getting hungry for French fries?”, but maybe that's just me.

I agree with you, the combination of question mark/close quote/comma jammed together like that looks clumsy.

Depending on the sentence, I think you could maybe rectify this by using a dash; if there is some space around the dash, I think it looks less ugly:

> The one thought that keeps running through my brain is, “Is anyone else getting hungry for French fries?” – but maybe that's just me.

For further analysis on the matter, [Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_(speech)_marks_punctuation_in_or_out.htm) has an interesting related post.